# Select rows that doesn't exist in a previews query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

**1- Dis**

```
Oid || Name
```

**2- CS**

```
Oid || Name || Dis
```

**3- Crit**

```
Oid || CS || Date
```

I have a Query that gives me the name of the Dis and CS that matches the current month and year:

```
   SELECT Dis.Oid as 'DisOid', Dis.Name as 'Dis', CS.OID as 'CsOid' ,CS.Name  as 'CS'
     FROM Crit, CS, Dis
    WHERE Crit.CS=CS.OID AND Dis.OID=CS.Dis 
      AND convert(datetime,CONCAT(YEAR(getdate()),'-',Month(getdate()),'-01 00:00:00')) = convert(datetime,CONCAT(YEAR(Crit.Date),'-',Month(Crit.Date),'-01 00:00:00')) 
 ORDER BY Dis.Oid DESC
```

What I need, is to get the Cs that doesn't exist on that previous query, I made this:

```
   SELECT Dis.Oid as 'DisOid', Dis.Name as 'Dis', CS.OID as 'CsOid' ,CS.Name  as 'CS'
     FROM Crit, CS, Dis
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Crit.Oid 
     FROM Crit WHERE Crit.CS=CS.OID) 
      AND Dis.OID=CS.Dis 
      AND convert(datetime,CONCAT(YEAR(getdate()),'-',Month(getdate()),'-01 00:00:00')) = convert(datetime,CONCAT(YEAR(Crit.Date),'-',Month(Crit.Date),'-01 00:00:00')) 
 ORDER BY Dis.Oid DESC
```

But its not working correctly, it gives me CS duplicates and I'm not sure if it gives me the CS that doesn't exist in the current month and year.

How can I make it work correctly? I don't fully get the 'NOT EXISTS' and I don't know if that is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change the not exist to a not in:

```
SELECT distinct Dis.Oid as 'DisOid', Dis.Name as 'Dis', CS.OID as 'CsOid' ,CS.Name  as 'CS'
FROM Crit, CS, Dis
WHERE cs.name not in (select rest of query)
```

I cannot copy the rest of the subquery.

Comment: If I do that, it brings me a lot of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
SELECT dis.oid    AS 'DisOid', 
       dis.[name] AS 'Dis', 
       cs.oid     AS 'CsOid', 
       cs.[name]  AS 'CS' 
FROM   cs, 
       dis 
WHERE  dis.oid = cs.dis 
       AND cs.oid NOT IN (SELECT cs.oid 
                          FROM   crit, 
                                 cs, 
                                 dis 
                          WHERE  crit.cs = cs.oid 
                                 AND dis.oid = cs.dis 
                                 AND CONVERT(DATETIME, Concat(Year(Getdate()), 
                                                       '-', 
                                                       Month( 
                                                       Getdate()), 
                                                       '-01 00:00:00') 
                                     ) = CONVERT(DATETIME, Concat( 
                                         Year(crit.date), '-', 
                                                           Month(crit.date), 
                                                           '-01 00:00:00') 
                                         ))
```

I don't know if is the ideal way to do it, but it does the work in a reasonable time.